# Issue with Fluentbit sending my app docker container Logs to ELK

Tags: json, parsing, multiline, elk, fluent-bit

I want to parse and send below JSON Logs to ELK

```
[2023-12-05 11:24:35.281] INFO  JsonLogger [[MuleRuntime].uber.8614: [rtf-eks-vali-dev].post:\notification:api-config.BLOCKING @32b79a38] [event: de6ad1b0-9360-11ee-9395-8e6b4b575608]: {
  "correlationId" : "de6ad1b0-9360-11ee-9395-8e6b4b575608",
  "message" : "This is O/P from JSON Logger",
  "tracePoint" : "EVENT",
  "priority" : "INFO",
  "elapsed" : 0,
  "locationInfo" : {
    "lineInFile" : "138",
    "component" : "json-logger:logger",
    "fileName" : "api-routes.xml",
    "rootContainer" : "post:\\notification:api-config"
  },
  "timestamp" : "2023-12-05T11:24:35.281Z",
  "applicationName" : "cn-memory-check-sys",
  "applicationVersion" : "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "environment" : "dev",
  "threadName" : "[MuleRuntime].uber.8614: [rtf-eks-vali-dev].post:\\notification:api-config.BLOCKING @32b79a38",
  "metadata" : {
    "User-Agent" : "PostmanRuntime/7.35.0",
    "Host" : "dev-cn1-apis.com.cn",
    "Content-Length" : "227",
    "Content-Type" : "text/plain"
  }
}
```

2022-07-25T06:43:17.20958947Z stdout F kind of line is getting appended before each json element such as correlationId,message,etc.

How to get rid of docker appended lines?

I tried different multiline and custom parsers and filters but none of them worked.

Comment: Below i can see in ELK as output  - ??\u0000e??s\u0017\u0004wÂ´?log??2023-12-20T08:44:35.385893663Z  [2023-12-20 08:44:35.370] INFO JsonLogger [[MuleRuntime].uber.13052: [rtf-eks-vali-dev].post:\\notification:api-config.BLOCKING @32b79a38] [event: 009ee640-9f14-11ee-9395-8e6b4b575608]: {??\u0000e??s\u0017?$??log?c2023-12-20T08:44:35.385941296Z    \"correlationId\" : \"009ee640-9f14-11ee-9395-8e6b4b575608\",??\u0000e??s\u0017?????log?U2023-12-20T08:44:35.385949639Z

Comment: Below is the output : "��\u0000e���9�PV��log��2023-12-20T10:24:02.964610901Z stdout F [2023-12-20 10:24:02.864] INFO  JsonLogger [[MuleRuntime].uber.13101: [roche-rtf-eks-vali-dev].post:\\notification:api-config.BLOCKING @32b79a38] [event: e58638a0-9f21-11ee-9395-8e6b4b575608]: {��\u0000e���9�ě��log�c2023-12-20T10:24:02.964652651Z stdout F   \"correlationId\" : \"e58638a0-9f21-11ee-9395-8e6b4b575608\",��\u0000e���9��Ձ�log�U2023-12-20T10:24:02.964659141Z stdout F   \"message\" : \"This is O/P from JSON Logger\",��\u00

Comment: Please don't post things into comments, use the [edit] link + choose best format for it.